# Transferir as chaves e valores de um JSON para variáveis PHP

Tags: php, json, array, variáveis

Como transferir os dados de uma JSON:

`{"resultado":true,"cadastros":[{"id":"12345","nome":"Augusto","idade":"30"},{"id":"23411","nome":"Carlos","idade":"93"},{"id":"13451","nome":"Bruno","idade":"23"}],"mensagem":"Success"}`

Para variáveis em PHP tendo como resultado:

```
`$id[0] = "12345"; $nome[0] = "Augusto"; $idade[0] = "30"; $id[1] = "23411"; $nome[1] = "Carlos"; $idade[1] = "93";`
```

e também a quantidade de registros, que no total desse exemplo são 3.

`$registros = "3";`

Tentei utilizar o json_decode() junto com o foreach() mas não funcionou. Não sei como desenvolver a lógica.

```
<?php   
    $json = '{"resultado":true,"cadastros":[{"id":"12345","nome":"Augusto","idade":"30"},{"i‌​d":"23411","nome":"Carlos","idade":"93"},{"id":"13451","nome":"Bruno","idade":"23‌​"}],"mensagem":"Success"}'; 
    $a = json_decode($json, true); 
    echo $a;   
?>
```

resulta em

> **Notice:** Array to string conversion in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\teste.php on line 4

Array linha 4 é o `echo $a;`

Comment: Qual o resultado do `json_decode()`?

Comment: `<?php
$json = '{"resultado":true,"cadastros":[{"id":"12345","nome":"Augusto","idade":"30"},{"id":"23411","nome":"Carlos","idade":"93"},{"id":"13451","nome":"Bruno","idade":"23"}],"mensagem":"Success"}';
$a = json_decode($json, true);
echo $a;
?>` resulta em `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\teste.php on line 4
Array` linha 4 é o echo $a;

Comment: Inserí o seu comentário na pergunta. Pode sempre editar a pergunta para acrescentar detalhes. Agora que o comentário está na pergunta pode apagar o comentário aqui. Eu também vou apagar quando você vir isto. Bemvindo!

Comment: O que aparece quando testa `var_dump($a);`, antes do `echo` ?

Comment: Consegui resolver 90% do problema com a solução do Filipe: `$a_Dados = json_decode($json, true);
echo $a_Dados["resultado"]."<br>"; //true
echo $a_Dados["cadastros"][1]["nome"]; //12345` Agora falta conseguir a quantidade de registros que são 3. Como proceder?

Comment: @user3486019: teste `count($a_Dados["cadastros"]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) com o segundo parâmetro "true", assim será retornado um array associativo, ou seja, itens formados por um par chave e valor, no qual cada chave possui um valor associado.

Um exemplo, onde $url é o link para o json.

```
$a_Dados = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
echo $a_Dados["resultado"]; //true
echo $a_Dados["cadastros"][0]["id"]; //12345
```

Se for necessário, faça um for:

```
$a_Dados = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
for($i=0; $i<count($a_Dados["cadastros"]); $i++){
    echo $a_Dados["cadastros"][$i]["id"];
}
```

Se possuir uma variável codificada em json, altere a seguinte linha:

```
 $a_Dados = json_decode($variavel_codifica_json,true);
```

Comment: Você resolveu 90% do meu problema. Tem alguma maneira prática de conseguir a quantidade de cadastros?

Comment: Fechou. Obrigado.

Comment: @user3486019 sim, basta fazer isso $total = count($a_Dados["cadastros"]); $total será igual a quantidade de cadastros, ou então veja a segunda parte que postei, tem um "for" em cima da chave "cadastros".